# Phonegap plugin for version 2.0

Tags: iphone, cordova, xcode4.2, phonegap-plugins

*Well, I am pretty new to phone gap. A day back, I got it installed on MAC OSX 10.7.1 with Xcode version 4.2.*

- First thing, I couldn’t see an option in my Xcode to create phone gap application. However I can make it happen using terminal. (Later came to know, that is how it works on this version, probably).
- Second, I followed [this tutorial](http://nathancampos.me/post/23831039066/how-to-setup-and-use-nativecontrols-in-phonegap) and tried to add [plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS). When I compile, it gives me fatal error. `'CDVPlugin.h' file not found`. But i could see it in the **Cordovalib.xcodeproj**

In **NativeControls.h**

```
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#else
#import "CDVPlugin.h"
#endif
```

*So can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong? Should I need to add CDVPlugin.h and related files again?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation worked after modifying both the files `NativeControls.h` and `NativeControls.m`:

Modified `NativeControls.h`:

```
//
// NativeControls.h
//
//
// Created by Jesse MacFadyen on 10-02-03.
// MIT Licensed

// Originally this code was developed my Michael Nachbaur
// Formerly -> PhoneGap :: UIControls.h
// Created by Michael Nachbaur on 13/04/09.
// Copyright 2009 Decaf Ninja Software. All rights reserved.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UITabBar.h>
#import <UIKit/UIToolbar.h>

//#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
//#else
//#import "CDVPlugin.h"
//#endif

@interface NativeControls : CDVPlugin <UITabBarDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    UITabBar* tabBar;
    NSMutableDictionary* tabBarItems;

    UIToolbar* toolBar;
    UIBarButtonItem* toolBarTitle;
    NSMutableArray* toolBarItems;

    CGRect  originalWebViewBounds;
}

/* Tab Bar methods
 */
- (void)createTabBar:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)showTabBar:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)hideTabBar:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)showTabBarItems:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)createTabBarItem:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)updateTabBarItem:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)selectTabBarItem:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;



/* Tool Bar methods
 */
- (void)createToolBar:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)resetToolBar:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)setToolBarTitle:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)createToolBarItem:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)showToolBar:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
- (void)hideToolBar:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;
/* ActionSheet
 */
- (void)createActionSheet:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;


@end
```

---

Modifications in the file `NativeControls.m`: in line 22, change `PGPlugin` to `CDVPlugin`

Hope this will help.

Comment: I re-edited my previous post. Try the solution above and let me know if this works :S...

Comment: Hello mate!! :) It works now without any error :) I was following this one http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS. It worked after changing the .h :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In Cordova 2.1 (only)
I got around this error by simply commenting out if/else for a given PushNotification plugin

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
//#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
//#else
//#import "CDVPlugin.h"
//#endif
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
```

Comment: I'm sure this is just a hack because something else in my project miss configured -- its build and working. Just fine for this time